# Python recursion with iterators (strange behavior)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, generator, yield

I wrote this code to try understand what's happening.

Can anyone help me understand why the generator is not calling itself recursively? 
How to write recursive generators?

```
def f_yield(n):
    print(n)
    if n < 5:
        yield n
    else:
        yield f_yield(n-3)

def f_return(n):
    print(n)
    if n < 5:
        return n
    else:
        return f_return(n-3)

[i for i in f_yield(12)]
# prints 12 

f_return(12)
# prints 12 9 6 3
```

Comment: Generator functions don't execute until you try and iterate them.

Comment: @khelwood what qualifies a function as a generator? I tried writing a function with a mix of return and yield statements and it behaves as a generator. Is this right? Thx.

Comment: @jimififi Yes, if the function contains a `yield` statement, it's a generator function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As khelwood pointed out, `f_yield(n-3)` is also an iterator, so it doesn't return unless you iterate over it. If you add `yield from`, the recursion starts to work:

```
def f_yield(n):
    print(n)
    if n < 5:
        yield n
    else:
        yield from f_yield(n-3)
```

Comment: Caveat here is that the list will be [3] as that is the only value that is actually yeilded, all the way down at the bottom of the recursion

Comment: @Artog The version with `f_return(n)` does that too. ;) The example is correctly a simplified one, as per minimum reproducible example rule - we can see the recursion, we can see an "identical" version with return that does work, we can see this doesn't work.

Comment: Actually the return example, as is, will return `None` for any n bigger than 5 :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over `f_yield(n-3)`
You can use [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html) to do this:

```
yield from f_yield(n-3)
```